# Android fastboot oem unlocking

Tags: android, unlock, fastboot

So I have got my phone in the bootloader and I want to unlock it
so I type `fastboot oem unlock <KEY>` and I get this

```
D:\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot oem unlock ***************
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
...
(bootloader) Check 'Allow OEM Unlock' in Android Settings > Developer
(bootloader) Options
OKAY [  0.008s]
finished. total time: 0.009s
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:- (Note - This worked for me till Android L,M and N on `Qualcomm's MSM` chipsets)

1. Enable developer Menu from Settings
2. From Developer Settings Enable OEM Unlocking
3. `adb reboot bootloader`
4. `fastboot oem unlock-go`
5. Device will reboot
   Partitions will get **unlocked**

Comment: Can you help me find the documentation for this? I can't find `fastboot oem unlock-go` anywhere.

Comment: Hi @GabrielFair : Unfortunately I donot have documentation for this.. this was bit of a tribal knowledge that just happen to work !

Comment: `fastboot oem unlock-go` says `< waiting for any device >` and thats it. The emulator doesn't get any popup as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot normally
2. Enter `Developer options`
3. Some option as `OEM unlocking` should be there. Enable it
4. Proceed as you were doing in fastboot.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What if it is "bricked" and does not boot? Can't I change this "setting" using fastboot?

Comment: Same question @Olaia, can you have any option from adb?

Comment: @AndréCaldas any luck with fastboot?

Comment: @SaadBilal: It was not for me. I didn't try anything. But I guess that you can use fastboot and burn the original (some signed) firmware. Then boot, then follow the instructions above to unlock.

Comment: You might be able to change it from fastboot if it's rooted, if it's not rooted, 100% sure you can not change it. But I do not know the setting to change it.

Comment: Also, if you don't do the above, some partitions will be protected and you will not be able to flash those, so you might actually end up with an unstable device.

Comment: That's the bad news for me because my phone is in boot loop and my OEM settings are locked. I have heated the phone to get started with developer options but unable to bypass boot loop, is there any way i can boot my phone so that i can enable the OEM lock and update img.